# Does homotopy type of a map $S^1 \to RP^1$ defines a homotopy type of $(D^2, S^1)\to (RP^2, RP^1)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, projective-space, cw-complexes

Consider a CW structure on $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with one 2-cell, one 1-cell $\mathbb{R}P^1$, and one 0-cell. Let $f \colon
(D^2, \partial D^2) \to (\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{R}P^1)$ be a map such that $f \big|_{\partial D^2}$ is homotopic to
the attaching map $\phi \colon \partial D^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$ of the 2-cell. Does this imply that $f$ is
homotopic to the characteristic map $i \colon (D^2, \partial D^2) \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ of the 2-cell, as maps of pairs?

Comment: I'm not sure. But, it does imply that $\Bbb RP^1\sqcup_{f|\partial D^2}D^2\simeq\Bbb RP^2$. Which maybe gives exactly what you want, actually

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{R}P}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$

I believe the answer is no.

Let's focus on the map $\pi_2(\RP^2, \RP^1) \to \pi_1(\RP^1)$ in the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for the pair $(\RP^2, \RP^1)$. If this map is injective, it implies that the homotopy class of a map $(D^2, S^1, x_0) \to (\RP^2, \RP^1, y_0)$ is uniquely determined by the homotopy class of its restriction $(S^1, x_0) \to (\RP^1, y_0)$.

Now, consider the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for $(\RP^2, \RP^1)$:
$$
\dots \to \pi_2(\RP^2) \cong \Z \to \pi_2(\RP^2, \RP^1) \xrightarrow{j} \pi_1(\RP^1) \cong \Z \xrightarrow{t} \pi_1(\RP^2) \cong \Z_2 \to \dots
$$

Note that the kernel of $t$ is $2\Z$. Consider the short exact sequence (SES):
$$
0 \to \Z \xrightarrow{l} \pi_2(\RP^2, \RP^1) \xrightarrow{j} 2\Z \cong \Z \to 0
$$

Since we can define $u \colon \Z \to \pi_2(\RP^2, \RP^1)$ such that $ju = \mathrm{id}_\Z$ by taking any preimage of a generator of the last $\Z$, the SES splits. Therefore, $\pi_2(\RP^2, \RP^1) \cong \Z \oplus \Z$, and $j$ is not injective.

It's important to note that this reasoning provides an answer for a pointed version of the question, considering maps between pointed spaces and homotopies preserving basepoints. Nevertheless, it is plausible that the unpointed version can be reduced to the pointed one.

(I would like to thank @Thorgott for pointing out mistakes in the first version of this answer and for several helpful comments)

Comment: It is not true that $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{R}P^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. The group to the left in the SES is $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)=\pi_2(S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$ and to the left of that is $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^1)=\pi_2(S^1)=0$. Otoh, the image of $j$ is $2\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$ as you point out, so we obtain a SES $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{R}P^1)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0$, which splits necessarily. The approach is sound, though.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, and sorry for the mistake. Am I right that $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{R}P^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, and the map on the left of $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{R}P^1)$ is an inclusion of one $\mathbb{Z}$, while the map on the right is the projection to the other followed by the multiplication by 2, and, therefore, $f_*^{(2)}$ must be an inclusion of the second $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You are right about everything but the final claim. The diagram's commutativity only allows you to conclude however that the second component of $f_{\ast}^{(2)}$ is the identity, but it says nothing about the first component. By the way, note that the pointed version of your original question is precisely equivalent to asking whether the boundary map $j$ is injective, which you can answer in the negative by just the bottom row of your diagram. The unpointed question should actually be equivalent to the pointed question, but that detail's a bit annoying.

Comment: @Thorgott I believe your last comment provides a complete answer to my question (I believe that the unpointed version is equivalent to the pointed one). If you prefer, you can write your reasonings as an answer. (Then, perhaps, I could delete my initial "answer" as it contains a wrong statement)

Comment: @Thorgott Could you please clarify what you mean by the second and the first component of $f_*^{(2)}$? I believe that once $f_*^{(1)}$ is provided, we can trace the images of the generator of $\pi_2(D^2, \partial D^2)$ to determine the exact form of $f_*^{(2)}$... Am I mistaken?
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I think your answer would be just fine after fixing this error. What I meant by "components" are the factors when you consider this map into $\pi_2(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{R}P^1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. Such an isomorphism is obtained from a splitting of $j$ (as map to $2\mathbb{Z}$) and the second component is obtained by post-composing with $j$, so we can read it off from the diagram. The first component most definitely depends on the choice. For what it's worth, there is a choice s.t. the generator maps to $(0,2)$.